# yauzl returning Error: end of central directory record signature not found

Tags: amazon-s3, node-modules, unzip

The following Node JS code always fails with:

> Error: end of central directory record signature not found

I tried it with several kinds of zip files.

```
  // Retrieve the snapshot, which will be a zip file
  S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: snapshotPath}, (err, response) => {
    console.log(`Snapshot length: ${response.Body.length}`);  // confirmed the length is the same as the test file
    if (err) {
      throw(err);

    } else {

      fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/test.gz', response.Body);  // (debug) confirmed this writes out a zipped file identical to the original

      yauzl.fromBuffer(response.Body, {lazyEntries: true}, function(err, zipFile) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`ERROR getting zipFile: ${err}`);
          throw err;
        }


        // never makes it to here

        // this will recurse through the gz file
        // in our case we will have only one file, but it will be very large
        zipFile.readEntry();
        zipFile.on('entry', function(entry) {
        ...
```

The test file is being mocked like so:

```
   aws.mock('S3', 'getObject', (params, callback) => {
      if (params.Key.includes('Metadata')) {
        ...
        });
      } else {
        console.log(`Mocking snapshot...`)
        callback(null, {
          AcceptRanges: "bytes",
          LastModified: "Fri, 19 Jun 2020 16:38:33 GMT",
          ContentLength: 940,
          ETag: "\"85ca928a4d8766c8bd53607c6782db0f\"",
          ContentType: "binary/octet-stream",
          Metadata: {},
          Body: Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sample-data/sb2'))
        });
      }
```

I tried different encodings on readFileSync.
The length of the file that yauzl is opening, 940, agrees with the size of the test zip file.
Writing the file out before zipping it creates a file that is unzippable.
I tried using a file gzip'ed on the mac, also tried a zip file created using gzip on linux.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

yauzl does not handle gzip or gunzip.  See https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/issues/104